# Pasar dos parametros a funcion desde cadena html

Tags: jquery

Me gustaría poder pasarle otro parámetro mas a la función "ctrEntradaAlamcen()"

```
html+="<button type='button' onclick='ctrEntradaAlmacen("+objJsonV[i].id+")' class='btn btn-light'>"+ objJsonV[i].name +"</button>";
```

Esta linea se la asigno a una variable que después asigno a un div.
Si fuera con javascript con poner  ctrEntradaAlmacen(1,2); lo tendría arreglado, mi duda es qeu no se muy bien como poner la ",".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, seria asi:

```
html+="<button type='button' onclick='ctrEntradaAlmacen("+objJsonV[i].id+","+otroParametro+")' class='btn btn-light'>"+ objJsonV[i].name +"</button>";
```